# How to start xfce4 session inside upstart user session?

Tags: lightdm, xfce, upstart, mythbuntu

I would like to use a upstart user session to run some jobs under user control. My machine has mythbuntu installed which means I have lightdm which starts an xfce4-session. How should I replace my current configuration to have my xfce4-session running under `init --user`?

At the moment my `/usr/share/xsessions/mythbuntu.desktop` runs `/usr/share/mythbuntu/session.sh` which does `exec startxfce4` which runs `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` which in turn runs `xfce4-session`. I'm not sure into which part of this chain to execute `init --user` and then how to resume the chain. Do I need to create a user job that executes whatever I replaced with `init --user`?